# VHDL ALU undefined value

Tags: undefined, vhdl, alu

I'm learning VHDL for programming a FPGA, basic (but hard-for-me) projects. I have this ALU. It is supossed to be a 4-bit ALU. But when I want to make the **Add** operation the value of `result` is `UUUU`. For all other operations is working fine.

Any advise?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity ALU is
    Port (
                clk: in std_logic;
                reset: in std_logic;
                operation: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
          );
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is
    signal A : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0001";
    signal B : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "1111";
    signal result : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal flags : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);   -- [S,OF,Z] 
begin

    process (operation) begin
        flags <= (others => '0');
        result <= (others => '0');
        case operation is
            when "000" => 
                result <= std_logic_vector((unsigned("0000"&A) + unsigned(B)));
                flags(1) <= result(4);
            when "001" =>
                if (A >= B) then
                    result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned("0000"&A) - unsigned(B));
                    flags(2) <= '0';
                else
                    result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned("0000"&B) - unsigned(A));
                    flags(2) <= '1';
                end if;
            when "010" =>
                result <= "0000"&A and "0000"&B;
            when "011" =>
                result <= "0000"&A or "0000"&B;
            when "100" =>
                result <= "0000"&A xor "0000"&B;
            when "101" =>
                result <= not ("1111"&A);
            when "110"  =>
                result <= not ("1111"&B);
            when "111" =>
                result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) * unsigned(B));
            when others =>
                result <= (others => 'Z');
        end case;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see all `U`s happening (with the code as is) is if the process *never* executes.  Which means you must have no transactions on the `operation` signal for the add operation.

Which only raises more questions:

Are you definitely getting `U`s (not `X`s maybe?):  is something else driving the signal as well?

Can you post your testbench code?

Comment: Yep, completely sure they are U's. I'll post later the testbench code. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The first two things that come to mind looking at your code are:

1. You should include `A` and `B` in the process sensitivity list (now it only contains `operation`).
2. You can't use `result(4)` to set `flags(1)`, as `result(4)` will only be updated after the process, and `result` itself isn't on the sensitivity list again so the process won't be triggered again to reflect the changed value. The best option is probably to store the sum in a `variable`, then assign that to `result` and the overflow bit.

Comment: As Martin Thompson pointed out, if you get `UUUU` from `result`, then the process is never being executed, and thus my points above won't fix your issue (though I think they are problems you'll encounter once you fix the behaviour of your test bench).